# My Code hangs My browser .Why?

Tags: php

What is wrong with my `PHP` code. The result becomes infinity and makes my browser hang. Can any one tell it is a Virus or NOT ?

CODE:

```
<?php
$counter = 10;

while( $counter =3) {
    echo "$counter";
}
?>
```

Comment: You're not decreasing `$counter` anywhere.

Comment: the little hamster in a wheel powering your server is tired.

Comment: See the [while documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.while.php). Assign and decrease values are incorrect / missing.

Comment: A virus that somehow affects PHP while loops? I don't understand how you possibly came to that conclusion.

Comment: @EkoostikMartin - it would be a pretty evil virus tho.

Comment: Why the question is tagged with `javascript`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

May be its halepful:-

:-here you put integer 10 in $counter variable

```
        <?php    $counter = 10;    ?>
```

now in while loop you do a process like:-you put integer 3 in the variable $counter again.

so after completing this process (putting integer 3 in the $counter variable) the process return **true**

the while loop will run till the process return **true** and ends when process return false

```
        <?php

       while( $counter =3) {// this is turn condition so loop will not stop
        echo "$counter";
       }

        ?>
```

ok just in this case while loop will run like
Example **case 1:**

```
     <?php
     while(TRUE){

      //code will run
      echo $counter;
      //it will only give you output 3333333....to the ends of end. like this

       }
       ?>
```

Example **case 2:**
if the process return false then while loops ends

```
                        <?php
                        while(FALSE){
                        //code will not run
                        }
                        ?>
```

In last words:-
loop or condition will only be run when the process out come will true

Comment: May i know who is doing negative to my answer

Answer (score 6):

`$counter = 3` *assigns* the value 3, and since 3 is truthy it passes the `while` condition. What you have is not a virus, it's just a very nice infinite loop.

Comment: Worth mentioning that assignment also returns the value assigned, so `($counter = 3) == 3`.

Answer (score 2):

You're using `=` instead of `==` in your while loop. As a result `$counter` is assigned the value of three. Since it is always 3 and your loop never ends.

Answer (score 1):

Assignment in PHP returns the value you assigned, which is an issue because your `while` condition contains an assignment. `($counter = 3)` returns `3`, which is truthy, so your `while` loop executes every time, causing your browser to hang.

The fix is to make sure you use **comparison**, not **assignment** in your `while` loop, and to decrement the `$counter` variable with each iteration, or as appropriate:

```
$counter = 10;

while( $counter == 3) {
    echo "$counter";
    $counter -= 1;
}
```

Comment: i think he simply misunderstands the while as until ( until($counter==3){ $counter--; }